# How to speed up SSH login?

Tags: configuration, ssh

From outside of my house, whenever I login to my Ubuntu server using SSH, it takes about 6 seconds for me to get the prompt for password, however when I login to my web hosting server it takes about 1 second. What can I do to speed this up?

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=hardy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 8.04.1"
$ ssh -v
OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Dual-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 1210
cpu MHz         : 1000.000
cache size      : 1024 KB
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:      2074528 kB
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The number one reason I've seen for this is a configuration option in SSHD `UseDNS` this option (enabled by default) causes the server to perform DNS resolution on the incoming requests. A time consuming operation. I've seen logins go from one minute plus waiting for password prompt to under a few seconds. If you edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server and add (if it's not there) at the bottom `UseDNS no` then restart the SSH daemon with `service ssh restart` you should see an improvement next time you connect.

Comment: Better to fix your DNS configuration.

Comment: This worked out great!! Thanks! The login time went from 20-30 secs to less than 5 secs :)

Comment: What is the benefit of having `UseDNS` enabled?

Comment: Be aware! when you set the directive `UserDNS` after a `Match` directive you'll get an error: `is not allowed within a Match` block if you restart the sshd you'll not be able to ssh into your server. I did this mistake and I got locked out of my server. Always remember do not add any directive at the bottom of `sshd_config` if you have `Match` directive in it.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the reason number 2 (after the server-side UseDNS option) for long SSH session logins are client side attempts to connect using IPv6 (which, obviously, isn't set up correctly on my network - or almost any other network, for that matter).

See [HOWTO: Speed up SSH login](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=84399) on Ubuntu forums.

The "solution" is to enable IPv4 only:

1) either for the given SSH client invocation:

```
ssh -4 login@hostname
```

2) or globally in ssh client conffiguration in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
   AddressFamily inet
```

Of course, it would be more correct to set up IPv6 on your network properly, but who has the time for that :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the next option with your ssh command:

```
-o "PreferredAuthentications=password"
```

(this prevents ssh from negotiating any other authentication method, and speeds up the password promtp!)

Comment: Why use passwords at all? Why not keys?

Comment: Easy: because you may not be allow to use keys! (sshd not configured to use them, bad user file permissions, etc.9

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, type this on the remote machine (as the user you would log in as) to suppress any MOTD messages:

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

Doesn't make as much a difference as turning off `UseDNS` but it might help on slower connections.

Comment: -1: The MOTD is only displayed after a successful login. This will not cause the password prompt to appear any faster.

Comment: True, but still a useful comment.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a rather old Ubuntu version, it might well be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/300151

Restarting dbus (`/etc/init.d/dbus restart`) might help.

Comment: I have a 10.04 box upgraded from 9.04 and 9.10. Restarting dbus reduced `time ssh remoteServer date` from 8s to 0.5s.